# Where To Store Intermittent Data

Tags: java, conventions

If for example I had a user class:

```
public class User{
private String name;

public User(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}
```

And had a listener that is triggered once a player clicks:

```
public class ClickListener implements Listener{

public void run(String someInt){

}
```

If these variables were to be used in a different class to be used for some function only once. Would it better to have a:

```
HashMap<User, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

in the listener and then remove the user after the method requiring someInt is completed, or have a:

```
    private String someStr;

public String getSomeStr(){
    return someStr;
}

public void setSomeInt(){
    this.someStr = someStr;
}
```

in the User class and then set the value to null after it has been used.

Which is a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you give some more context on what you are doing?  Why not just pass it as a parameter the the function you call.  No need to store it anywhere.

Comment: Well, you cannot set the `int` primitive to `null`. However, there may be many other design considerations beyond what you have outlined here that would suggest the solution. For example, depending upon what is using the other data, perhaps an `Observer` pattern would be a better choice than either of the ones suggested.

Comment: @puhlen To give more context, I started working at a firm and found that the main user class looks like this: https://hastebin.com/ocegacahej.http . A lot of the variables will be set to a certain value, then a listener will check what that value is then set it back to a default value. I thought it kind of looked messy but didn't want to bring it up without any other notes about it.

Comment: @KevinO sorry I intended for it to be more psuedo code then anything. See my above comment if that helps with the context more.